# How to resolve my web app formatting using CSS for apps created with python-dash

Tags: css, plotly-dash

I have used python dash and CSS to create a web calculator but it has different formatting on different screens even though I am using relative measurements in my CSS code.

[Web app image on my Laptop screen (Developed here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwNOO.png)

[Web app image on my PC screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7nZo.png)

My small CSS code snippet for reference

```
#input_div {
width: 33%;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 1.32%;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
margin-bottom: 0%;
padding-bottom: 0.85%;
font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;}

#invested_amnt {
padding-top: 0.8%;
margin-top: 0.8%;}

#est_returns {
padding-top: 0.8%;
margin-top: 0.8%;}

#total_value {
padding-top: 0%;
margin-top: 0%;}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Regarding your question, what do you mean by "it is showing different formatting"? How does it look different? Maybe you can attach some screenshots.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have attached two screenshots in the question, with title as web app image on laptop and web app image on PC. Please refer to those. Also, different formatting as in the padding space or margin space is different on different screens